# Using both leaf and stem images for plant disease detection using convolution neural network?

Tags: python, image-processing, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am conducting a research on plant disease detection using Deep Learning methods. The method I'll use is called CNN (Convolution Neural Network). The disease symptom is coloring of the plants leave and stem. When I review previously conducted researches, almost all of them used images only leaf or stems of the plant, but not both. How can I use both stem and leaf images in the data set to train my model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way I can think of is to have a two stream network:

1. One network takes in the leaf only. The other takes in the
   corresponding stem.
2. These two networks then connect together at some higher layer and from
   there reach the output layer.

The idea is that each network below performs a feature transformation of the corresponding image on their own to derive useful features and then these two sets of features are combined at the higher layers before being used by  even higher layers to generate a prediction.

```
    output
  /\/\/\/\/\
  _________
 |         |
 |_________|
 / \ / \ / \
 ____    ____
|cnn1|  |cnn2|
|____|  |____|
  ^       ^
 Leaf    Stem
```